# Possible to make Facebook registration plugin dynamic?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

So I have a Facebook registration plugin on my site that is working really well.I'm using a simple iframe with JSON form data ..Is there any way to make this form dynamic? For example, if a user chooses his state,  I want the next field to display all churches etc.. in that user's state..I can do this normally, but would it be possible to do this from within the iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible with the current registration plugin https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/

What you can do is when the user is redirected back to your site, you can take the value of state out of the signed_request and then have the user enter in the church.

Comment: Ok thanks ...takes a bit away from user xp, but I guess using leveraging the power of Facebook is worth the cost.

Comment: Excellent assertion, it is worth it in my opinion too.